# How to use FirstOrDefault for two primary keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

there are two primary key a and b
one key can be compiled
how about two keys

```
var product = db.TMP_HELLO.FirstOrDefault<TMP_HELLO>(instrmnt => (instrmnt.a == good.a; instrmnt.b == good.b));
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get?  The first where *both* `.a` and `.b` match, or *either* `.a` or `.b`?

Comment: You will need to use logical operators, in this case `&&` should do the trick `db.TMP_HELLO.FirstOrDefault<TMP_HELLO>(instrmnt => instrmnt.a == good.a && instrmnt.b == good.b);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `&&` operator in your lambda.

```
var product = db.TMP_HELLO
        .FirstOrDefault<TMP_HELLO>(
            instrmnt => instrmnt.a == good.a && instrmnt.b == good.b);
```